# What value does this Exception formatting function add over the built in ToString() method

Tags: c#, exception

I was perusing our large code base I came across this function which is used to format an exception:

```
    private static string FormatException(Exception ex)
    {
        var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
        errorMessage.AppendLine($"ErrorMessage : {ex.Message}");
        if (ex.Data.Count > 0)
        {
            var additionalMessage = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var key in ex.Data.Keys)
            {
                additionalMessage.Append($" {key} : {ex.Data[key]}");
            }
            errorMessage.AppendLine($"AdditionalMessage : 【 {additionalMessage} 】");
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ex.StackTrace))
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine($"StackTrace : {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            errorMessage.AppendLine($"InnerException : {ex.InnerException.ToJson(false, true)}");
        }
        return errorMessage.ToString();
    }
```

At first sight it appears, to me, to offer no real value over the built in `ToString()` method, given that the information is just going to be run written to a log file.

Am I missing something subtle in the `ToString()` method that would require something like to ensure the `Exception's` information is fully collected.

Comment: You can have a look at default implementation of [`ToString()`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,438) method and compare with yours

Comment: It might "only" go to a log file, but what happens after that?  In our company we have a standard format that our Elastic stack expects from all our Apps.  Maybe this was created to meet a similar requirement?

Comment: The only thing that is extra is that the `Data` dictionary is displayed. However, I have never come across an exception where this was actually filled. So I would say the implementation doesn't have a benefit over just ToString.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I see - good one.